# How to assign id to table items in Jquery dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

```js
success: function(response) {
  console.log(response);


  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var trHTML = '';
    for (var j = 0; j < response[i].Products.length; j++) {

      trHTML += '<tr class="clickable-row" data-href="index.html"><td>' + response[i].IP + '</td><td>' + response[i].Products[j].Product + '</td><td>' + response[i].Products[j].CVECount + '</td></tr>';
      // console.log(response[i].Products[j].Product);
      console.log(trHTML);

    }
    $('#ProductsTableBody').append(trHTML);
  }

  $('.js-exportable').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    responsive: true,
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
  });


},
```

I have this code. I want to assign unique id to each of them dynamically. And also I want to make them clickable table items. After they clicked according to their id  I fetch another information from backend and direct another page. How can I assign id's to table items dynamically and make them clickable.

Comment: `<td id="td"'+ j +'>' +response[i].IP + '</td>'`?

Comment: @ShadowFiend, if we will use only `j` as id, then there will be same values for `j` for every `i` so this won't make unique `id` for all tr.

Comment: oh yeah.. better to use both i and j..

Comment: @Doruk S, I hope you got solution for your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your dynamic `<tr>` like this with `id` attribute like this:

```
trHTML += '<tr class="clickable-row" id="id_'+i+'_'+j" data-href="index.html"><td>' + response[i].IP + '</td><td>' + response[i].Products[j].Product + '</td><td>' + response[i].Products[j].CVECount + '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Himanshu thank you for answer, I have another question How can I call function with i,j parameter when that table item clicked.

Comment: Thank you for up vote @DorukS, You can do that using class of the tr like: `$(document).on('click','.clickable-row',function(){ //your code will go here });`